# C# won't loop around my loop

Tags: c#, winforms, list, stringbuilder

I'm attempting to go around a loop and append items to a StringBuilder.

However, I'm unable to do anything within the loop, and I don't think my loop is even being accessed.

Below is the code:

```
string initialString = "PRINT OUT PRODUCTS BELOW!\n";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(initialString);

for (int i = 0; i < products.Count(); i++)
{
   stringBuilder.Append(products.ElementAt(i));
   stringBuilder.Append("24");
   stringBuilder.Append("36");
}

stringBuilder.Append("45");

return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The final "45" will print, but the 24 or 36 will not.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are there any items in products?

Comment: this is *probabbly* because products.Count() is equal to 0

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line and look what happens. Your code seems good, so `products` has probably no elements

Comment: Note: You're calling `Count()` and `ElementAt` n times each: that is VERY expensive. Use a regular `foreach` loop instead.

Comment: @dcastro Compiler won't optimize Count()? products aren't changing in the loop so it can assume, that Count() result will be always the same.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Actually, you can't say that `Count()` will always return the same result. `Count` is a LINQ extension that works with the `IEnumerator` returned by any custom implementation of `IEnumerable`. I can create my own `CustomList<T>` that returns a randomly generated `IEnumerator` each time.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Also, to give you a more realistic scenario, I can be using a concurrent collection and adding products from a different thread.

Comment: @dcastro if you add products from a different thread, foreach is very dangerous. Compilers are smart and can predict if there is possibility that Count() can return varied values. It CAN be expensive. It depends on data structure.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa 1) I said "concurrent collections" - as in, thread-safe collections. .NET's concurrent collections return an `IEnumerator` that represents a snapshot of the collection (a copy, if you will), so it's safe to enumerate on them with a `foreach` loop. 2) How exactly would a compiler predict that? It would have to figure the `IEnumerable`'s concrete type (e.g., `List`, `Queue`, etc) - which it does **not** - and it would have to look inside its `GetEnumerator` implementation and figure out in which situations would the result value change - which it also does **not**.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa as a result, `Count()` will be evaluated on each iteration. And if you look for LINQ's source code, you'll see that this is computed in constant O(1) time _only_ for instances of `ICollection<T>` (considering a proper implementation) and in linear O(n) time for all other implementations. So yes, chances are it will be expensive. And even if it wasn't, having `ElementAt` in the loop makes the code run in exponential O(n^2) time.

Comment: @dcastro I've got it, thanks. Btw. O(n^2) is polynomial, not exponential ;)

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Thanks x) my math days are long gone... sigh

Answer (score 7):

If you don't see `24` and `36` then your products list is empty. There is nothing wrong with your code.

BTW you can build same string with [String.Join(string separator, IEnumerable values)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
String.Join("2436", products) + "45"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think my loop is even being accessed

[Use the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

In general you should avoid `ElementAt` on a query that is not a collection because it always needs to execute in in the loop to get to the index. Instead use `ToList` first or better `foreach`:

```
foreach(var product in products)
{
   stringBuilder.Append(product.ToString());
   stringBuilder.Append("24");
   stringBuilder.Append("36"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

two possible reasons
1) Your product.Count is 0
2) Or you disturb the product list during loop on which loop is being run

please don't use ElementAt this can disturb your loop so I will suggest you to use foreach loop